# Hadith about Licking others fingers after eating?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, sunnah, muslim-practices

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Regarding etiquettes of eating :

> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbas that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: “When one of you eats food, let him not wipe his hand until he has licked it or has someone else to lick it.”([ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1273770))

What does the part "or has someone else to lick it" mean? 
In what context can this be understood? How can it be lawful to lick another person's finger? 
Please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Waalykom  Alsalam Werahmato Allah ,

Licked by others who are not harmed by it; such as a small child, wife or husband .
That there is a blessing in some parts of the food, and fear the Messenger of Allah peace be upon him to waste this blessing if the food remains in the fingers.

Comment: You should add evidences and mark your quotation to distinguish it from your own words.

Comment: So why shouldn't strangers be allowed to receive this blessing? Why would they be harmed by it?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualikum Brother,

Very good question, this question is actually pushed by extremist Christian missionaries to attempt to disprove the Prophet's (PBUH) prophethood. I would actually prefer you to Farid Responds' video on this. I believe it was called "A response to 10 reasons Muhammad (PBUH) is not a" by Farid Responds. He gives a very good explanation, which would be way better than any I could give you. I believe it has something to do with the way the Arabic was translated.